# Move backwards, rotate and re plan a global path

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I am using:

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value = "SBPLLatticePlanner"/>
 <param name="base_local_planner" value="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS" />
```

I have experienced that when the robot is going to passed through a narrow doorway, it gets stuck.

I am trying to figure out how to set the following strategy when the robot gets stuck.

1.-A parameter that allows the robot to move certain meters backwards.

2.-Set the angle for the robot to rotate and make the robot rotate that angle

3.-Re plan the global path

If it can go trough the doorway, it is fine if not go to step 1

Well, probably I may need to write my own plug in, right?

Can you give me an advice on how to start it :)

I hope you can help me and in advance thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200797/move-backwards,-rotate-and-re-plan-a-global-path/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-07**:
Hello, currently im looking into the "moving backward" feature to unstuck the robot. have you found a solution or anything useful to share with regards to this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS` plugin for local planner, and set its `min_vel_x` parameter to negative value. This answer is based on [my](http://answers.ros.org/question/225835/robot-moves-forward-only/) question.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1